# DELETE rows without relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could someone help me with this? I have 3 tables as shown below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cp,qr,lu;
CREATE TABLE public.cp
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    job_id bigint NOT NULL,
    domain_id bigint NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.qr
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    checkpoint_id bigint NOT NULL,
    objectguid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (checkpoint_id)
        REFERENCES public.cp (id)
);
CREATE TABLE public.lu(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    objectguid uuid NOT NULL,
    domain_id bigint NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(1,11);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(2,22);
INSERT INTO cp(job_id, domain_id) VALUES(9,1);
SELECT * from cp;
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(1, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(1, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(2, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(2, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(3, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a3111');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(3, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a3111');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(4, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0422');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(4, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0422');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(5, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a5222');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(5, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a5222');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(6, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0691');
INSERT INTO qr(checkpoint_id, objectguid) VALUES(6, '637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0691');
SELECT * from qr;
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111',1);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111',1);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211',1);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211',1);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a3111',11);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a3111',11);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0422',2);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0422',2);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a5222',22);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a5222',22);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0691',1);
INSERT INTO lu(objectguid, domain_id) VALUES('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0691',1);
SELECT * from lu;
SELECT * from cp;
```

Now I am trying to delete all `lu` records that fall under a specific `cp.job_id`
I have `cp.id`, I want to first find all `cp` records with matching `job_id`, then delete matching `lu` records. For instance, given `cp.id=1`, I want to delete only 4 records from `lu`
I am trying code like this, but no luck

```
DELETE FROM lu
USING cp
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT FROM qr
    WHERE qr.objectguid = lu.objectguid
    AND cp.domain_id=lu.domain_id
    AND cp.id=1
);
```

Comment: For cp.id=1, there are two records in "cp" with same job_id & domain_id. These two cp.id's could have one or more "qr" records each. I am trying to find all those qr records in lu, and delete them from lu.

SELECT id FROM cp
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1)
AND domain_id IN (SELECT domain_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1);

SELECT objectguid FROM qr WHERE checkpoint_id IN (1,2);

DELETE FROM lu 
WHERE domain_id IN (SELECT domain_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1)
AND objectguid IN (above list);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the `USING` without a join condition.

You found the solution yourself in a comment:

```
DELETE FROM lu
USING cp
WHERE cp.domain_id = lu.domain_id
  AND cp.domain_id=1
  AND cp.job_id=1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM qr
              WHERE qr.objectguid = lu.objectguid
                AND qr.checkpoint_id = cp.id);
```

Comment: Hi Albe, Thanks for the reply. This still deletes 6 records. There are two records in "cp" with same job_id & domain_id. These two cp.id's could have one or more "qr" records each. I am trying to find all those qr records in lu, and delete them.

SELECT id FROM cp
WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1)
AND domain_id IN (SELECT domain_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1);

SELECT objectguid FROM qr WHERE checkpoint_id IN (1,2);

DELETE FROM lu 
WHERE domain_id IN (SELECT domain_id  FROM cp WHERE id = 1)
AND objectguid IN (above list);

Comment: I don't understand. Please describe which of those 6 rows should not be deleted and why.

Comment: DELETE FROM lu 
WHERE domain_id IN (SELECT domain_id FROM cp WHERE id = 1)
AND objectguid IN ('637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111',
'637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0111',
'637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211',
'637779d2-6d43-4639-b427-5323aa2a0211')

Comment: "qr" is a running table that holds incremental changes per domain & per job. When these changes come in, new cp (checkpoint) is created and changes are dumped into "qr". During commit, "qr" records are shredded into "lu" that holds most current state for each object represented by objectguid. This is all working great. Problem is when we want to reset all objects in "lu" per domain per job (basically given the cp.id) Thanks for taking time to look at this.

Comment: DELETE FROM lu
USING cp
WHERE cp.domain_id = lu.domain_id
  AND cp.domain_id=1 AND cp.job_id=1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT FROM qr 
              WHERE qr.objectguid = lu.objectguid
    AND qr.checkpoint_id = cp.id);

Comment: That last statement deletes only four rows. Does that mean that you found the solution (that I still don't quite understand) yourself?

Comment: Last statement was built off of your idea. Hence I want to accept your idea as the solution. Unfortunately, I don't have 15 reputation points to cast my vote. My great thanks to you nevertheless.